# pandas groupby-apply behavior, returning a Series (inconsistent output type)

Tags: python, pandas

I'm curious about the behavior of pandas groupby-apply when the apply function returns a series.

When the series are of different lengths, it returns a multi-indexed series.

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df1=pd.DataFrame({'state':list("AABBB"),
   ...:                 'city':list("vwxyz")})

In [3]: df1
Out[3]:
  city state
0    v     A
1    w     A
2    x     B
3    y     B
4    z     B

In [4]: def f(x):
   ...:         return pd.Series(x['city'].values,index=range(len(x)))
   ...:

In [5]: df1.groupby('state').apply(f)
Out[5]:
state
A      0    v
       1    w
B      0    x
       1    y
       2    z
dtype: object
```

This returns a a `Series` object.

However, if every series has the same length, then it pivots this into a `DataFrame`.

```
In [6]: df2=pd.DataFrame({'state':list("AAABBB"),
   ...:                 'city':list("uvwxyz")})

In [7]: df2
Out[7]:
  city state
0    u     A
1    v     A
2    w     A
3    x     B
4    y     B
5    z     B

In [8]: df2.groupby('state').apply(f)
Out[8]:
       0  1  2
state
A      u  v  w
B      x  y  z
```

Is this really the intended behavior? Are we meant to check the return type if we use apply this way? Or is there an option in `apply` that I'm not appreciating?

In case you're curious, in my actual use case, the returned Series will be the same length as the length of the group. It seems like an ideal case for `transform` except that I've found that `apply` with returning a Series is actually an order of magnitude faster on a large dataset. That can be another topic.

Edit: Loosely based on the Parfait's answer, we can certainly do this:

```
X=df.groupby('state').apply(f)
if not isinstance(X,pd.Series):
    X=X.stack()
X
```

That will give the same output type for either `df=df1` or `df=df2`. I guess I'm just asking if this is really the normal or preferred way to handle this.

Answer (score 8):

In essence, a dataframe consists of equal-length series (technically a dictionary container of Series objects). As stated in the pandas [split-apply-combine](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) docs, running a *groupby()* refers to one or more of the following

> - Splitting the data into groups based on some criteria
> - Applying a function to each group independently
> - Combining the results into a data structure

Notice this does not state a data frame is always produced, but a generalized *data structure*. So a `groupby()` operation can downcast to a Series, or if given a Series as input, can upcast to dataframe.

For your first dataframe, you run unequal groupings (or unequal index lengths) coercing a series return which in the "combine" processing does not adequately yield a data frame. Since a data frame cannot combine different length series it instead yields a multi-index series. You can see this with print statements in the defined function with the `state==A` group having length 2 and `B` group length 3.

```
def f(x):
    print(x)
    return pd.Series(x['city'].values, index=range(len(x)))

s1 = df1.groupby('state').apply(f)

print(s1)
#   city state
# 0    v     A
# 1    w     A
#   city state
# 0    v     A
# 1    w     A
#   city state
# 2    x     B
# 3    y     B
# 4    z     B
# state   
# A      0    v
#        1    w
# B      0    x
#        1    y
#        2    z
# dtype: object
```

However, you can manipulate the multi-index series outcome by resetting index and thereby adjusting its hierarchical levels:

```
df = df1.groupby('state').apply(f).reset_index()
print(df)

#   state  level_1  0
# 0     A        0  v
# 1     A        1  w
# 2     B        0  x
# 3     B        1  y
# 4     B        2  z
```

But more relevant to your needs is [unstack()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) which pivots a level of the index labels, yielding a data frame. Consider `fillna()` to fill the `None` outcome.

```
df = df1.groupby('state').apply(f).unstack()
print(df)

#        0  1     2
# state            
# A      v  w  None
# B      x  y     z
```

Comment: I understand _why_ this happens, but it just seems strange still. If I'm not working interactively, it seems I have to check the data type of the result to proceed. Calling `.reset_index()` or `.unstack()` will still have wildly different results depending on whether I started with `df1` or `df2` data.

Comment: Good point though about using `stack` and `unstack` being the best way to coerce between the two output types, thanks. I've edited the question to include this.

Comment: Well as mentioned `groupby().apply()` does not guarantee a data frame return as it depends on the inputs and operations and so can yield different structures. Consider a user defined function/class to handle the various output.

Comment: `apply` will return a multi-indexed series if the function given to `apply` returns series with different indexes. Otherwise if all the Series returned by the function given to apply have the same index, apply will return a Dataframe

Answer (score 5):

instead of doing `index=range(len(x))` in your function f, you
can do `index=x.index` to prevent this undesired behavior