# Inconsistent behaviour of groupby.apply()

Tags: python, pandas

When doing a `df.groupby(...).apply(...)` there seems to be an inconsistency in the return format of the operation between when the number of groups is > 1 or = 1. It returns a dataframe instead of a series when there is only one group.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a'], 'B': range(4), 'C': [1, 2, 3, 4]})        

    A   B   C
0   a   0   1
1   a   1   2
2   a   2   3
3   a   3   4

df.groupby('A').apply(lambda x: x['B']*x['C'].shift())

A     0   1   2   3         
a   NaN 1.0 4.0 9.0
```

With multiple groups:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a','b'], 'B': range(5), 'C': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})

    A   B   C
0   a   0   1
1   a   1   2
2   a   2   3
3   a   3   4
4   b   4   5

df.groupby('A').apply(lambda x: x['B']*x['C'].shift())

A   
a  0    NaN
   1    1.0
   2    4.0
   3    9.0
b  4    NaN
```

I would like to get a Series in both cases, or at least make it consistent without having to check if there's only one group or not. There are some threads mentioning this issue but I couldn't find any fix.

Comment: it is not an inconsistency: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37715246/pandas-groupby-apply-behavior-returning-a-series-inconsistent-output-type

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to add `squeeze=True` in the groupby.

Comment: FYI..`%timeit df1.groupby('A', squeeze=True).apply(lambda x: x['B']*x['C'].shift())` returns 3.82 ms ± 259 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

Comment: And... `%timeit df1['B'] * df1.groupby('A')['C'].transform('shift')` returns 839 µs ± 4.38 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)