# Unclear why groupby with single group produces row DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Here's two `groupby` operations on a `pandas.DataFrame`:

```py
import pandas


d = pandas.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                      "b": [1, 2, 4, 3, -1, 5]})

grp1 = pandas.Series([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
ans1 = d.groupby(grp1).apply(lambda x: x.a * x.b.iloc[0])

grp2 = pandas.Series([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2])
ans2 = d.groupby(grp2).apply(lambda x: x.a * x.b.iloc[0])

print(ans1.reset_index(drop=True))
# a  0  1  2  3  4  5
# 0  1  2  3  4  5  6

print(ans2.reset_index(drop=True))
# 0     1
# 1     2
# 2     3
# 3    12
# 4    15
# 5    18
# Name: a, dtype: int64
```

I want the output in the format of `ans2`. If the grouping Series has more than one group (as in `grp2`), then there is no issue with the output format. However, when grouping Series has only one group (as in `grp1`), the output is a `DataFrame` with a single row. Why is this?

How can I ensure that the output will always be like `ans2` regardless of the number of groups in the grouping Series? Is there a quicker/better approach than

1. Checking if the output is a DataFrame and coercing into a Series
2. Checking if the grouping Series has only one group and avoiding `groupby` if that's the case

Comment: Related [pandas groupby-apply behavior, returning a Series (inconsistent output type)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37715246/15497888)

Comment: It's really just a super odd edge-case. `groupby` expects _groups_ and it is weird to call groupby when you _should_ just operate on the entire DataFrame itself. It's also an issue with `apply` needing to be able to return a general output, so pandas really needs to be flexible and try to figure out what's best. While yes, `groupby` probably should handle this correctly to make code more flexible for a variety of inputs, I'd honestly just add a check like `if grp.nunique() == 1; my_func(df); else: df.groupby(grp).apply(lambda gp: my_func(gp))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution is to return a `DataFrame` from `apply`:

```
import pandas


d = pandas.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                      "b": [1, 2, 4, 3, -1, 5]})


grp1 = pandas.Series([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])


ans1 = d.groupby(grp1).apply(lambda x: x[['a']] * x.b.iloc[0])

grp2 = pandas.Series([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2])
ans2 = d.groupby(grp2).apply(lambda x: x[['a']] * x.b.iloc[0])

print(ans1.reset_index(drop=True))
#    a
# 0  1
# 1  2
# 2  3
# 3  4
# 4  5
# 5  6

print(ans2.reset_index(drop=True))
#     a
# 0   1
# 1   2
# 2   3
# 3  12
# 4  15
# 5  18
```

To understand why, the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) of `apply` function is helpful. When the function given to `apply` returns a `Series` they are converted to a row and final output is a `DataFrame` with one row per group. So the behaviour of `grp1` is actually expected.

This begs the question why does the second case using `grp2` return a `Series`. I think that is because the two groups return `Series` with different index values. Thus the results of the two groups are appended in a single row with multi-level indexing (as seen below).

```
d = pandas.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                      "b": [1, 2, 4, 3, -1, 5]})

grp2 = pandas.Series([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2])
def func(x):
    z= x.a * x.b.iloc[0]
    print(z.index)
    return z
ans2 = d.groupby(grp2).apply(func)
# Int64Index([0, 1, 2], dtype='int64')
# Int64Index([3, 4, 5], dtype='int64')

print(ans2)
# 1  0     1
#    1     2
#    2     3
# 2  3    12
#    4    15
#    5    18
# Name: a, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens because, as you have only one group with `grp1`, the intermediate is casted first as Series, and then as DataFrame with the group as index, instead of adding a level of MultiIndex like with `grp2`.

To avoid this, you can slice your data as dataframe in your lambda and subset the column to Series only after aggregation. This ensures that the intermediate result will remain in the right dimension:

```
>>> ans1 = d.groupby(grp1).apply(lambda x: x[['a']] * x.b.iloc[0])['a']
>>> ans1
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    5
5    6
Name: a, dtype: int64

>>> ans2 = d.groupby(grp2).apply(lambda x: x[['a']] * x.b.iloc[0])['a']
>>> ans2 
0     1
1     2
2     3
3    12
4    15
5    18
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

That said, the easiest remains to use `transform`:

```
>>> d.groupby(grp1)['a'].transform(lambda x: x*d.loc[x.index[0], 'b'])
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    5
5    6
Name: a, dtype: int64

>>> d.groupby(grp2)['a'].transform(lambda x: x*d.loc[x.index[0], 'b'])
0     1
1     2
2     3
3    12
4    15
5    18
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Well spotted that this only happens when series are returned from `.apply(…)` but I’m not sure that this fundamentally explains *why* the behaviour is different with different numbers of groups. I’d expect a multi-index series in the case with a single group, not a dataframe with the series’ index as columns and one group per row. Nonetheless this gives a good workaround so +1.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest is to avoid `.apply()` which indeed do weird things when recombining. This is probably because the semantics of this function are so vague. You can return anything and pandas will do its best to guess what you meant

If you want consistent results with functions that apply to the whole sub-dataframe you’re better off running the function yourself:

```
>>> pd.concat({n: (lambda x: x.a * x.b.iloc[0])(g) for n, g in d.groupby(grp1)})
1  0    1
   1    2
   2    3
   3    4
   4    5
   5    6
Name: a, dtype: int64
>>> pd.concat({n: (lambda x: x.a * x.b.iloc[0])(g) for n, g in d.groupby(grp2)})
1  0     1
   1     2
   2     3
2  3    12
   4    15
   5    18
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

Now what I would recommend is instead to use a function with a well defined return shape. Here `.transform()` could be of use:

```
>>> d.groupby(grp1)['b'].transform('first')
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    1
5    1
Name: b, dtype: int64
>>> d.groupby(grp2)['b'].transform('first')
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    3
4    3
5    3
Name: b, dtype: int64
```

Here’s an example of how you could use for the same calculation:

```
>>> ans1 = d.copy()
>>> ans1['a'] *= d.groupby(grp1)['b'].transform('first')
>>> ans1
   a  b
0  1  1
1  2  2
2  3  4
3  4  3
4  5 -1
5  6  5
>>> ans2 = d.copy()
>>> ans2['a'] *= d.groupby(grp2)['b'].transform('first')
>>> ans2
    a  b
0   1  1
1   2  2
2   3  4
3  12  3
4  15 -1
5  18  5
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way, other than using `transform`, to ensure you have the same output format is to use `squeeze`:

```
>>> ans1.squeeze().reset_index(drop=True)
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    5
5    6
Name: 1, dtype: int64

>>> ans2.squeeze().reset_index(drop=True)
0     1
1     2
2     3
3    12
4    15
5    18
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

You can use `squeeze=True` in `groupby` but it will raise a `FutureWarning`:

> FutureWarning: The `squeeze` parameter is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.